# Could not resolve reference to '' in property 'Database'. '' is invalid. Provide valid scoped name

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-foxpro, data-migration, biml

I am working on a data migration project, from Visualfoxpro to Oracle...!
I have successfully created the meta data and the packages script in BIML but when i tried to generate the SSIS package in Visual Studio, it give an error "Could not resolve reference to '' in property 'Database'. '' is invalid.". 
I am  not sure what Database name should be used for and Oracle DB as it's schema driven(In my understanding).
I have followed the article http://bimlscript.com/Walkthrough/Details/73
Changed 1-2-Environment.biml in the following way

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <OleDbConnection Name="Source" ConnectionString="Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=<Path to VFP database folder>;Exclusive=false;Nulls=false;" />
    <OleDbConnection Name="Target" ConnectionString="Data Source=ServerName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;" />
  </Connections>
  <Databases>
    <Database Name="NameForTheDatabase" ConnectionName="Target" />
  </Databases>
  <Schemas>
    <Schema Name="OracleSchemaName" DatabaseName="" />
  </Schemas>
</Biml>
```

Since i am new to this technical stack, I am struggling to get a solution for this issue. Any input will be very helpful.

Comment: For the VFP connection string, if it IS a Database, the Data source CAN include the actual name of the database, not just the path...  ex.:  "C:\YourPath\ToData\YourDatabase.dbc", not sure if that is the missing part, but you can explicitly add the database name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you just need the same DatabaseName in Databases and Schemas.

```
  <Databases>
    <Database Name="NameForTheDatabase" ConnectionName="Target" />
  </Databases>
  <Schemas>
    <Schema Name="OracleSchemaName" DatabaseName="NameForTheDatabase" />
  </Schemas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already tried this. "NameForTheDatabase" is just a name for our reference in BIML or it should be the Database name of the Oracle schema?

Comment: `[Databases].[Database name]` should be the name of your actual database. `[Schemas].[DatabaseName]` should have the same value as `[Databases].[Database name]` and `[Schemas].[Schema Name]` should be the actual name of the schema you're using.

Comment: This is the error i am getting while generating the SSIS packages. "Could not resolve reference to 'Target.OracleSchemaName' in property 'Schema'. '' is invalid. Provide valid scoped name. Property Schema."